Toy modification, remote control, battery to usb
i would like to modify a few toys to change it from manually pressing 1 or 2 buttons on the toys to using remote (IR?) control. and I would like to change it from battery driven to usb and be able to map all of them (around 10) to one remote control.
How to do it? And where to get the parts?

Parts
A is the manual button.
B is where the sound comes from.
Part C

Part D


please ask only one question ... post the other question separately ... also, do not ask where to buy parts, it is not allowed

buy a remote controlled relay

To externally power, determine the battery voltage (measure the two wires coming from battery compartment), and then purchase a low-voltage AC-to-DC power converter of the correct output voltage, remove the batteries, connect DC power output to those battery wires, observing the correct polarity.   This is much easier than converting 5Vdc USB power to that supplied by the battery.
